# Why does date.valueOf() == date result in false?

Tags: javascript

[image: Date]

[image: Object]

Why does `date.valueOf() == date` result in `false`, but `a = {}; a.valueOf() = () => 3; a.valueOf() == a` result in `true`?

Comment: `valueOf()` returns a string, which is not `==` to an object

Comment: `a={} a.valueOf ==a` is false for me

Comment: For future reference, it's much more helpful to include the code, rather than a picture. A [mcve] is extremely helpful to people who might answer your question.

Comment: `Date.valueOf()` is different from `new Date().valueOf()`. The first returns a function, the latter a number, both not a Date object.

Comment: a.valueOf ==a is returning false but a.valueOf() ==a is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `number == object`, the [Abstract Equality Comparison spec algorithm](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) converts the object to a primitive using an operation called [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive), then that primitive to a number. For most things, that means `valueOf()` is preferred. For dates specifically, the new-in-ES6 `Symbol.toPrimitive` method is defined, which overrides the default ToPrimitive to return a string. You end up comparing `d.valueOf() == d.toString()` instead of `d.valueOf() == d.valueOf()`.

Don’t use `==`.

> When ToPrimitive is called with no hint, then it generally behaves as if the hint were Number. However, objects may over-ride this behaviour by defining a @@toPrimitive method. Of the objects defined in this specification only Date objects (see 20.3.4.45) and Symbol objects (see 19.4.3.4) over-ride the default ToPrimitive behaviour. **Date objects treat no hint as if the hint were String.**

```js
const d = new Date();
console.log(d.valueOf() == d);
delete Date.prototype[Symbol.toPrimitive];
console.log(d.valueOf() == d);
```

[In ES5](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8):

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, **unless O is a Date object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String**.

Comment: I don't see how this supports a case for "*Don’t use ==*". In this case, the use of `==` or `===` gives the same result. As far as I'm aware, comparisons of values other than primitives are very rare. In the case of primitives, using `===` exclusively instead of `==` causes just as many issues as exclusively using `==` instead of `===`. Far better that a developer understands the comparison algorithms and how different Types will be compared, then makes an informed decision on which comparison to make.

Comment: @RobG: `==` either does a) the same thing as `===`, or b) a relatively complex thing. You can use it in (a) scenarios if you like the way it looks. I discourage using it in (b) scenarios except in the idiomatic `== null` case, because having to even consider its several confusing edge cases is so easily avoided.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, date's valueOf will return UTC in string format. So when you compare a string UTC to a datetime Object. Ofcourse it will return false even if with .

```
var d= new Date();

var result = d.valueOf() == d;
console.log(d.valueOf())
alert(result);
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/keysl183/nhj34wde/2/

The second condition throws false for me.

== will only try to exlicitly convert the comparator and comparison but in this case JS will not do it accurately. On the other hand even if the strict ===. This will also throw false for both cases.

Comment: The fiddle has an error – it tries to assign a value to a function call.

Comment: Good catch, it seems jsfiddle doesn't save my changes. Thanks tho!

Comment: "*date's valueOf will return UTC in string format*". It does not, [*Date.prototype.valueOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.valueof) returns a number, the time value (milliseconds since 1970-01-01).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the output of `d.toString()` and "d"  then you find that its same output. It means when you type "d" then it will call `d.toString()` internally.

But according to the javascript object property, it should call `valueOf()`. I think it's an exception case.

And `d.valuOf()` return milliseconds which is number.

So `d.valueOf() == d`, is false because `d.valueOf()` return millisecods and `d` return `toString()` value which is string value of current date.